# IsGrounded in CharacterController not stable

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have following simple scene: scaled box at (0, 0, 0) for floor and 1 size box at (0, 2, 0). I try to do simple gravity and use following code:

```
private float gravity = 1.0f;
private Vector3 moveVector;

void Update()
{
    if (characterController.IsGrounded)
    {
        Debug.Log("is grounded");
        verticalVelocity = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("not grounded");
        verticalVelocity -= gravity;
    }

    Debug.Log("vertical velocity:" + verticalVelocity);

    moveVector.x = 0;
    moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
    moveVector.z = 0;

    characterController.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I see in log that event when object is on the floor I have grounded/not grounded messages. Visually object is on the floor and not oscillating.
Why I don't have constant "is grounded" when object is on the floor?
Maybe it is how CharacterController works but I can't find anything about it in documentation.

Comment: Can we see the code where `characterController.IsGrounded` is set?

Comment: @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé this property is controlled by Unity engine. I don't set it.

Answer (score 7):

You have to set Character Controller Min Move Distance to '0' (zero) or else you will always get this behavior, it is trying to limit how many times it checks if it's grounded, but at the end of the day gamers don't care, they will mash the jump button and call it buggy

Comment: This comment is not relevant. Min Move Distance does not affect this bug.

Comment: This might be true. I have a github project which seems to me to be very stable and performant in which I followed a different approach: https://github.com/koyima/fps-tutorial

Comment: what exactly did you do to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue

Just had some gravity when the character controller is grounded

Replace `verticalVelocity = 0;`

By 
   `verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;`

Comment: Unfortunately problem still here: isGrounded produce true and false. Do you have code example with correct logic?

Answer (score 2):

Setting "Min Move Distance" to 0 in the Character Controller Inspector solved a very similar problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Strubble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40126803/5015385) is right. You have to add some small gravity even if character is grounded.

```c#
if (characterController.IsGrounded)
{
    // Press the character down to the floor to avoid jitter "true-false"
    // of the isGrounded property.
    // To do it, add some small gravity (or velocity in your terms).
    verticalVelocity = -gravity * 0.1f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a Raycast with Vector3.down because I've tired of fixing it and it's really unreliable to use even while prototyping.